# Determine the exact interval of convergence of $\sum x^{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Determine the exact interval of convergence of the following power series:

$$\sum x^{n!}$$

**Theorem 23.1**
For the power series $\sum a_nx^n$, let $\beta=\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}$ and $R=1/\beta$.
The power series converges for $|x|<R$.
The power series diverges for $|x|>R$.

Any hints ? I don't know where to start, as  the power series isn't written as $\sum a_nx^n$.

Comment: Well if you want to apply your theorem, then obviously the first step is to rewrite the series in the form $\sum a_n x^n$.

Comment: 1 without thinking! because if 1<x it's clearly divergent!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use that Theorem, then rewrite it as $$\sum_ka_kx^k,$$ where $$a_k=\begin{cases}1 & k=n!\text{ for some }n\\0 & \text{otherwise},\end{cases}$$ and find the interval of convergence as described. Then all you need to do is determine whether it converges at the endpoints of the interval determined by the Theorem (that is, at $x=R$ or $x=-R$), which should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Wow, genius, took me some time to understand, but I get it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

If $|x|<1$, then $\sum |x|^{n!}\le \sum |x|^n$, so by comparison test, $\sum |x|^{n!}$. So $\sum x^{n!}$ also converges.

If $|x|=1$, then $\sum |x|^{n!}$  diverges trivially.

If $|x|>1$, then $\sum_{n\le N} x^{n!} \ge 2x + x^{N!}$ if $N>2$, and $x^{N!}$ is positive.  If you take $N\to\infty$, then $2x + x^{N!}$ diverges. So $\sum_{n\le N}x^{n!}$ also diverges.

So, interval of convergence of $\sum x^{n!}$ is $(-1,1)$.